# problems using custom fonts

Tags: fonts, font-face

I have been trying to use the custom font 'anders' in my CSS, but don't understand why it won't work.

Here is my code:

@font-face {
    font-family: 'andersregular'; 
    `src: url('Anders-webfont.eot');
}
    h1 {
``font-family:'andersregular';
}

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the path correct? Check your developer console. Can you see that the font is loaded?

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I'm not sure what a developer console is, I'm just using a text editor at the moment?

Comment: Depending on what browser you use you can use the developer tools built in. A quick Google search will help you find more info. I'm going to guess the path to the font is wrong. Where in your project is the font file located? And where is your css file? A basic project structure will help me solve your issue.

Comment: Ah OK, no it doesn't seem to be loaded when I look at dev tools.  I have the font file in the same file as my index.html and css file - they're all in the same folder.

Comment: Ah OK, no it doesn't seem to be loaded when I look at dev tools.  I have the font file in the same file as my index.html and css file - they're all in the same folder.

Comment: I tried to change the font with the following code, but still no luck!  @font-face {
 font-family: 'anders'; 
 src: url('Anders.ttf') format ('truetype');

Answer (score 0):

EOT font file format is only used by IE. Are you using a different browser? You'll need to include more formats to support other browsers.

You'll want to convert the font into the other necessary formats using a service like [Font Squirrel Web Font Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

And include the other formats in this way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'andersregular';
  src: url('Anders-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('Anders-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('Anders-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('Anders-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('Anders-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('Anders-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```